# How can ADFS be used with virtual directories in IIS?

Tags: iis, claims-based-identity, adfs, adfs2.0

I have IIS 7.5 installed. How can I configure a virtual directory so that it authenticates users against an instance of AD FS 2.0? I've tried modifying my web.config in a similar fashion to the way I modified it to work with C# web applications, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

How I have my federated structure configured is The Local web server applications are located on Server 1, The Web server/Federation Proxy (Remote Access/Web Proxy Server) are located on Server 2, IIS is installed on both Server 1 and Server 2. SSL Port on Server 2 is the default (443). SSL Port on Server 1 is (465**){those are not actually the * character}. Server 2 (The server that actually receives the web requests from outside of the domain) Has Virtual directories located in the default inetpub folder. In IIS I redirect the virtual folder to The application on Server 1 (so if the application name on server 1 is server1.domain.com/AppliactionOne, the virtual directory on Server 2 is Named {/ApplicationOne} and is accessible from the address or domain you have forwarded in your external dns  {external-address-or-domainName-for-server-2.com/ApplicationOne}. When setting up the forwarding address you need to forward the port for the address you configured in your router to Server 1 {https://external-address-or-domainName-for-server-2.com:465**/ApplicationOne} and open the port on Server 1  external-address-or-domainName-for-server-2.com:465**/ApplicationOne

This way the external Server 2 is still communicating authentication with the federation server. just be sure to set the reply address in your claims to have the port number configured for Server 1 and the same certificate installed as on your Server 2 Server.

Comment: Is this a answer to the question?